# Manipulating curl-obtained data before outputting

Tags: php, curl, echo

I'm using the below code to pull the html text from a site to publish on my own.

How can I manipulate the `curl` handle before `echo`?

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$returned = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

echo $returned;
```

Comment: just perform your manipulation on `$returned` its just a string. Also, you probably shouldnt be stealing content unless its explicitly allowed - and generally if thats the case there will be an API whish is much easier to work with than screen scraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate your returned data:

```
$returned = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$returned is the response so you can manipulate it
```

Did you mean something like this